# how to position button and dropdowns css-bootstrap

Tags: css, html, position, bootstrap-4

Hello im having some problems with the position of some dropdowns and buttons... i need to align them like this picture :

[image: How it should be]

How it is :

[image: How it is]

**The Code**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-6">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                Parametros Variables
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Modo :</label>
                <select [value]="modoSelected" class="form-control-mb-12" 
                 (change)="modo($event.target.value)">
                    <option value="MODO 1" >MODO 1</option>
                    <option value="MODO 2">MODO 2</option>
                    <option value="MODO 3" >MODO 3</option>
                </select>
                 <label>Intervalo de Guarda :</label>
                <select [value]="intSelected" class="form-control-mb-12"
                (change)="intSelection($event.target.value)" >
                    <option  value="1/4">1/4</option>
                    <option value="1/8">1/8</option>
                    <option  value="1/16">1/16</option>
                    <option  value="1/32">1/32</option>
                </select> <br><br>
                  <p> Capa A Capa B Capa C </p>
              <button (click)="onActivado()">{{ activado ? 'Desactivado' : 'Activado' }}</button>
              <select [(ngModel)]="select1" [disabled]="activado" (change)="saveValueA(select1)">
              <option *ngFor="let o of options | slice:0:getLimit(select1)" [ngValue]="o">{{ o }}</option>
              </select>
              <select [(ngModel)]="select2" (change)="saveValueB(select2)">
              <option *ngFor="let o of options | slice:0:getLimit(select2)" [ngValue]="o">{{ o }}</option>
              </select>
              <select [(ngModel)]="select3" (change)="saveValueC(select3)">
               <option *ngFor="let o of options | slice:0:getLimit(select3)" [ngValue]="o">{{ o }}</option>
              </select>

<br><br>
```

**the dropdowns and menus are all part of a card..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to arrange this like the pictured image, I think you might have more luck placing all of the elements into a table.